# How to reduce quadratic form using orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I wanted to reduce following quadratic form $f(x,y,z)=3x^2+3y^2+3z^2-xy-yz$

I found its symmetric metric but its eigenvalues too weird to start to for basis that convert to Eigen basis.

I am new to this topic I had just done diagonalization theory.

Please If some one suggested me how to tackle such problem I would be thankful

Comment: you did not type in an $xz$ term.

Comment: Dear Sir that term is 0, not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can do this without using orthogonal matrices,

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 6 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 6 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 35 }{ 6 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 35 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 35 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 35 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 6 }{ 35 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 35 }{ 6 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 204 }{ 35 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 35 }  &  \frac{ 6 }{ 35 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 6 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 35 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 6 }{ 35 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 35 }{ 6 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 204 }{ 35 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 6 }{ 35 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 35 }{ 6 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 204 }{ 35 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 6 }{ 35 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 6 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Dear Sir Thanks a lot . Sir If I wanted to do using orthogonal transformation , then can I do using orthoganalisation of above matrix . Or is there any simple method exist to directly find orthogonal matrix

Comment: @MathLover Orthogonal can also be done. One eigenvalue (as I typed it) is $6$ and the other two come from the quadratic formula. $ x^3 - 18x^2 + 106x - 204 = (x-6)(x^2 - 12 x + 34)$

Comment: @MathLover that is, the eigenvalues are $6, 6+\sqrt 2 \; , \; 6 - \sqrt 2 \; . \;$